# Can I use an Oyster card to travel to Welwyn Garden City?

Tags: trains, london, tfl, national-rail

I’ll be taking the Great Northern train from London’s King’s Cross station to Welwyn Garden City. Can I use an Oyster card for this? Is there a weekly pass that I can use? I’ll be traveling this route all weekdays for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFL have a map at https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/track/national-rail which shows where Oyster cards can be used. Welwyn garden city falls outside of this zone. Although there have been verious commitments and proposals to extend the scheme, like: http://www.whtimes.co.uk/news/oyster-card-setback-for-welwyn-hatfield-and-potters-bar-1-5267576

You can buy a season ticket valid for 1 week between any 2 stations, you can see the fare at: http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/seasonticket/search note that if you qualify for a railcard (https://www.railcard.co.uk) (you will likely quality for the Network railcard based on your question, and possibly more). It may be cheaper to buy the railcard and individual tickets rather then a weekly pass, this is because railcards offer a third off fares, but this does not extend to season tickets.

You can also purchase season ticks which include tube journeys, these may or may not be a cheaper option depending on your exact journeys.

Comment: I’m confused. WGC falls inside as per this map: http://content.tfl.gov.uk/london-rail-and-tube-services-map.pdf

Comment: @Korak I'm not sure I understand, wgc falls outside of the black dashes indicating where Oyster travel is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Welwyn Garden City is outside the Oyster area.

A 7-day season ticket between WGC and London Terminals is £73.10, and for £104.40 it will also cover local transportation in zone 1-6 (essentially the entire Greater London area).

For comparison an ordinary Anytime Day Return is £17.70.

Comment: +1 for answering, "no" rather than relying on the reader interpreting a diagram